# Plot a grid of Gaussians with Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

With the following code I'm able to draw the plot of a single 2D-Gaussian function:

```
x=linspace(-3,3,1000);
y=x';               
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/2);
surf(x,y,z);shading interp
```

This is the produced plot:

[image]

However, I'd like to plot a grid having a specified number x of these 2D-Gaussians.
Think of the following picture as an above view of the plot I'd like to produce (where in particular the grid is made of 5x5 2D-Gaussians). Each Gaussian should be weighed by a coefficient such that if it's negative the Gaussian is pointing towards negative values of the z axis (black points in the grid below) and if it's positive it's as in the above image (white points in the grid below).

[image]

Let me provide some mathematical details. The grid corresponds to a mixture of 2D-Gaussians summed as in the following equation:

[image]

In which each Gaussian has its own mean and deviation.

Note that each Gaussian of the mixture should be put in a determined (X,Y) coordinate, in such a way that they are equally distant from each other. e.g think of the central Gaussian in (0,0) then the other ones should be in (-1,1) (0,1) (1,1) (-1,0) (1,0) (-1,-1) (0,-1) (1,-1) in the case of a grid with dimension 3x3.

Can you provide me (and explain to me) how can I do such a plot?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed you said yourself, put (as an example just for the means)

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);  % //mesh

g_centers = -3:3;    
[x_g,y_g] = meshgrid(g_centers,g_centers); % //grid of centers (coarser)
mu = [x_g(:) , y_g(:)];  % // mesh of centers in column


z   = zeros(size(X));
for i = 1:size(mu,1)
     z= z + exp(-((X-mu(i,1)).^2+(Y-mu(i,2)).^2)/( 2* .001) );
end
surf(X,Y,z);shading interp
```

[image]

Comment: I c, thanks for pointing out the for cycle...but my difficulty was in guaranteeing that the Gaussians are centered on a fixed and predetermined grid. How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean? the grid is still the same one `(X , Y)`

Comment: I mean that each Gaussian of the mixture should be put in a determined (X,Y) coordinate, in such a way that they are equally distant from each other. e.g think of the central Gaussian in (0,0) then the other ones should be in (-1,1) (0,1) (1,1) (-1,0) (1,0) (-1,-1) (0,-1) (1,-1) in the case of a grid with dimension 3x3

Comment: All the time you want...thks for helping ;)

Comment: @Matteo, please have a look.